# Huggingface Transformers returning 'ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)', upon training a Bert binary classification model

Tags: python, nlp, classification, huggingface-transformers

I am learning how to use the Huggingface Transformers library, building a binary classification BERT model, on the Kaggle Twitter Disaster Dataset.

Upon entering the training loop, I get the following error, during the forward() function execution:

```
Epoch 1/50
----------
Aici incepe train_epoch

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py:477: UserWarning: This DataLoader will create 4 worker processes in total. Our suggested max number of worker in current system is 2, which is smaller than what this DataLoader is going to create. Please be aware that excessive worker creation might get DataLoader running slow or even freeze, lower the worker number to avoid potential slowness/freeze if necessary.
  cpuset_checked))

----Checkpoint train_epoch 2----
----Checkpoint train_epoch 2----
----forward checkpoint 1----

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-175-fd9f98819b6f> in <module>()
     23     device,
     24     scheduler,
---> 25     df_train.shape[0]
     26   )
     27     print(f'Train loss {train_loss} Accuracy:{train_acc}')

4 frames

<ipython-input-173-bfbecd87c5ec> in train_epoch(model, data_loader, loss_fn, optimizer, device, scheduler, n_examples)
     21         targets = d['targets'].to(device)
     22         print('----Checkpoint train_epoch 2----')
---> 23         outputs = model(input_ids=input_ids,attention_mask=attention_mask)
     24         print('----Checkpoint train_epoch 3----')
     25         _,preds = torch.max(outputs,dim=1)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
    887             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    888         else:
--> 889             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    890         for hook in itertools.chain(
    891                 _global_forward_hooks.values(),

<ipython-input-171-e754ea3edc36> in forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask)
     16                 input_ids=input_ids,
     17                 attention_mask=attention_mask,
---> 18                 return_dict=False)
     19 
     20         print('----forward checkpoint 2-----')

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
    887             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    888         else:
--> 889             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    890         for hook in itertools.chain(
    891                 _global_forward_hooks.values(),

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/transformers/models/bert/modeling_bert.py in forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask, token_type_ids, position_ids, head_mask, inputs_embeds, encoder_hidden_states, encoder_attention_mask, past_key_values, use_cache, output_attentions, output_hidden_states, return_dict)
    923         elif input_ids is not None:
    924             input_shape = input_ids.size()
--> 925             batch_size, seq_length = input_shape
    926         elif inputs_embeds is not None:
    927             input_shape = inputs_embeds.size()[:-1]

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

At first, I thought it was related to the return_dict=False change that they added, but I was wrong.
The code for the classifier and training loop is down below

Classifier:

```
class DisasterClassifier(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, n_classes):
        super(DisasterClassifier,self).__init__()
        self.bert=BertModel.from_pretrained(PRE_TRAINED_MODEL,return_dict=False)
        self.drop=nn.Dropout(p=0.3) # in timpul antrenarii, valori aleatorii sunt inlocuite cu 0, cu probabilitate p -> regularization and preventing the co-adaptation of neurons
        self.out = nn.Linear(self.bert.config.hidden_size,n_classes)
        
    def forward(self,input_ids,attention_mask):
        print('----forward checkpoint 1----')
        bertOutput = self.bert(
                input_ids=input_ids,
                attention_mask=attention_mask,
                return_dict=False)
        
        print('----forward checkpoint 2-----')
        output = self.drop(bertOutput['pooler_output'])
        return self.out(output)`
```

Training epoch:

```
optimizer = AdamW(model.parameters(),lr = 2e-5,correct_bias=False)
total_steps = len(train_data_loader)*EPOCHS
scheduler = get_linear_schedule_with_warmup(
                                            optimizer,
                                            num_warmup_steps=0,
                                            num_training_steps=total_steps)
loss_fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss().to(device)

def train_epoch(model,data_loader,loss_fn,optimizer,device,scheduler,n_examples):
 print('Aici incepe train_epoch') 
 model = model.train()
 losses =[]
 correct_predictions = 0
    
 for d in data_loader:
        print('----Checkpoint train_epoch 2----')
        input_ids = d['input_ids'].to(device)
        attention_mask=d['attention_mask'].to(device)
        targets = d['targets'].to(device)
        print('----Checkpoint train_epoch 2----')
        outputs = model(input_ids=input_ids,attention_mask=attention_mask)
        print('----Checkpoint train_epoch 3----')
        _,preds = torch.max(outputs,dim=1)
        loss = loss_fn(outputs, targets)
    
        correct_predictions += torch.sum(preds == targets)
        losses.append(loss.item())

        #backpropagation steps
        loss.backward()
        nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters,max_norm=1.0)
        optimizer.step()
        scheduler.step()
        optimizer.zero_grad()

   
 return (correct_predictions.double() / n_examples), np.mean(losses)
```

And the training loop:

```
history = defaultdict(list)
best_accuracy = 0

for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
    print(f'Epoch {epoch + 1}/{EPOCHS}')
    print('-' * 10)
    
    # train_acc,train_loss = train_epoch(model,
    #                                    train_data_loader,
    #                                    loss_fn,
    #                                    optimizer,
    #                                    device,
    #                                    scheduler,
    #                                    len(df_train))
    
    train_acc, train_loss = train_epoch(
    model,
    train_data_loader,    
    loss_fn, 
    optimizer, 
    device, 
    scheduler, 
    df_train.shape[0]
  )
    print(f'Train loss {train_loss} Accuracy:{train_acc}')
    
    val_acc, val_loss = eval_model(model,val_data_loader,loss_fn,device,len(df_val))
    print(f'Validation loss {val_loss} Accuracy:{val_acc}')
    print()
        
    history['train_acc'].append(train_acc)
    history['train_loss'].append(train_loss)
    history['val_acc'].append(val_acc)
    history['val_loss'].append(val_loss)

    if val_acc > best_accuracy:
        torch.save(model.state_dict(), 'best_model_state.bin')
        best_accuracy = val_acc
```

Has anybody encountered a similar situation?

Comment: Hi, I have the same error when using `BertTokenizer`. I do `encoding = tokenizer([[prompt, prompt, prompt], [choice0, choice1, choice2]], return_tensors='tf', padding=True))` and get `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`. When I do `encoding = tokenizer([[prompt, prompt], [choice0, choice1]], return_tensors='tf', padding=True)` it works. Any idea why? I want to fine-tune `TFBertForMultipleChoice` such that each question (`prompt`) has three choices and not two: https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/bert.html?highlight=formultiplechoice#tfbertformultiplechoice.

Answer (score 3):

I just had the same problem. You need to check the shape of **input_ids**, which should be (batch_size, seq_length). In your case, I guess it is something like (1, batch_size, seq_length) or whatever. So do:

```
input_ids = input_ids.squeeze(0)
outputs = model(input_ids=input_ids,attention_mask=attention_mask)
```